# Make a progressbar backcolor to transparent c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a progress bar in winform over a panel what i want is to make the backcolor of progresss bar to transparent so that any one can see the image of the panel through the progree bar

> I know we can use transparancy key and in winform and set that color to the progress bar back color but i want to make the progress bar backcolor to transparent and i think transaprancy key cannot be used in a panel so is there a way to make the progress bar backcolor to transparent??
>   when i put this code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        progressBar1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
}
```

It throws me some error like

> Control does not support transparent background colors.

Comment: The exception message leaves very little to the imagination.  Creating your own progress bar by deriving from the Control class is not particularly difficult.

Comment: ya maybe you are right but is there any way to do this???by some code?

Comment: I don't know why people vote some questions negative if they can't answer it. Bye the way i don't care and have solved the problem so check it who has vote this as negative.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This control properties is unsupported so let set the property first

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs p)
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        base.OnPaintBackground(p);
    }
```

now the control depends upon the parent control("Transparency style") so set it to transparent

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
```

Comment: This does not work for a ProgressBar. And is unnecessary for a Panel.